# Campaign CTI Automation

Tags: automation, campaign, campaign-member, sales

I wanted to know if there is any support for automation of calls in salesforce.

Basically, I want to automate campaigns such that we can dial calls to leads/contacts one by one (in order for all campaign members).

It would be great if you can share some of your valuable input.

Thank you.

Comment: You could make use of [Sales Dialer](https://www.salesforce.com/products/sales-cloud/features/lightning-dialer/) for this requirement.

Comment: Isn't it similar to click to dial functionality?